# Firebase App is not initialised in Capacitor JS Android Build

Tags: android, firebase, google-signin, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I have implemented Firebase Google Authentication in Capacitor JS using [@capacitor-firebase/authentication] (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@capacitor-firebase/authentication#capacitor-firebaseauthentication). It's working properly in the web app, but the application keeps crashing with the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.demo.application/com.demo.application.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialised in this process, com.demo.application. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
```

I have added a Google Service JSON file and also added plugins.

Android level grade:

```
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
 }
```

App level grade:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$androidxAppCompatVersion"
    implementation "androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:$androidxCoordinatorLayoutVersion"
    implementation "androidx.core:core-splashscreen:$coreSplashScreenVersion"
    implementation project(':capacitor-android')
    testImplementation "junit:junit:$junitVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:$androidxJunitVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$androidxEspressoCoreVersion"
    implementation project(':capacitor-cordova-android-plugins')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.1.1'
    implementation "com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.1"
}

apply from: 'capacitor.build.gradle'

try {
    def servicesJSON = file('google-services.json')
    if (servicesJSON.text) {
        apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
logger.info("google-services.json not found, google-services plugin not applied. Push Notifications won't  work."
}
```

How to initialise firebase app as I'm using JS SDK?

Reproducible [example](https://github.com/ts-geek22/capacitor-firebase.git) created with minimal [template](https://github.com/capawesome-team/.capacitor-app)

Answer (score 1):

I'm the maintainer of this plugin.
This error only occurs if you do not follow the [setup guide](https://github.com/capawesome-team/capacitor-firebase/blob/main/docs/firebase-setup.md) exactly.
If the problem persists, please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) using [this template](https://github.com/capawesome-team/.capacitor-app) in a public GitHub repository so I can debug the issue.

Comment: Reproducible https://github.com/ts-geek22/capacitor-firebase.git created with minimal https://github.com/capawesome-team/.capacitor-app.

Comment: The entire Android platform is missing in your example...

Comment: I haven't uploaded that on GitHub, but I have one on my local. Also, I have found the issue and solved it now. It has a missing configuration in the variable.gradle file.